# Scrollview is not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="mcb.myclickbazaar.Fragments.DateTimePlace">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout>
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout...>

                <LinearLayout...>

             </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The *scrollview is not working*. I have tried all the answers from stackoverflow, but still can't find a way to solve this issue.
This xml file is a fragment. It is one of the **fragment from tabbedView Activity**.

**EDIT**
***JAVA FILE***

```
package mcb.myclickbazaar.Activity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mcb.myclickbazaar.Fragments.DateTimePlace;
import mcb.myclickbazaar.Fragments.FinalBill;
import mcb.myclickbazaar.Fragments.ItemSelect;
import mcb.myclickbazaar.R;

public class ProceedingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemSelect.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        DateTimePlace.OnFragmentInteractionListener,FinalBill.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private static final String TAG = "ProceedingsActivity";
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_proceedings);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_proceedings);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_proceedings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ItemSelect(), "Select");
        adapter.addFragment(new DateTimePlace(), "DateTime");
        adapter.addFragment(new FinalBill(), "Bill");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

        Log.e(TAG,"Working: on onFragmentInteraction");
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

***Fragment Code***

```
package mcb.myclickbazaar.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import mcb.myclickbazaar.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link DateTimePlace.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link DateTimePlace#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class DateTimePlace extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private String upcoming_date_1,upcoming_date_2,upcoming_date_3,upcoming_date_4;
    private EditText editText_date;
    private EditText editText_time;
    private Spinner spinner_calendar;
    private Spinner spinner_time;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public DateTimePlace() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment DateTimePlace.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static DateTimePlace newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        DateTimePlace fragment = new DateTimePlace();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // Spinner element
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_date_time_place, container, false);

        spinner_calendar = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_calender);
        spinner_time = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_time);

        editText_date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_SelectDate_DTP);
        editText_time = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_SelectTime_DTP);

        editText_date.setFocusable(false);
        editText_time.setFocusable(false);

        editText_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner_calendar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner_calendar.performClick();
                editText_date.setHint("");
            }
        });

        editText_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                spinner_time.performClick();
                editText_time.setHint("");
            }
        });

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner_calendar.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories_calender = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories_calender.add("Today");
        categories_calender.add("Tomorrow");
        categories_calender.add(getUpcoming_Date(2));
        categories_calender.add(getUpcoming_Date(3));
        categories_calender.add(getUpcoming_Date(4));
        categories_calender.add(getUpcoming_Date(5));

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_calendar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories_calender);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter_calendar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner_calendar.setAdapter(dataAdapter_calendar);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner_time.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories_time = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories_time.add("9AM - 11AM");
        categories_time.add("11AM - 1PM");
        categories_time.add("1PM - 3PM");
        categories_time.add("3PM - 5PM");
        categories_time.add("5PM - 7PM");

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter_time = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories_time);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter_time.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner_time.setAdapter(dataAdapter_time);



        return view;
    }

    private String getUpcoming_Date(int upcoming){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date dt = new Date();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, upcoming);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM", Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        return formattedDate;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Comment: use NestedScrollview and add fillviewport=true. also remove upper relative layout

Comment: I tried but it didn't work!
Can You please explain a bit?

Comment: first replace Scrollview with Nestedscrollview and remove   android:isScrollContainer="false" line

Comment: Where is your Fragment? share you fragment code as well xml and java.

Comment: @reverie_ss are you trying same .xml what you post above?

Comment: @VinodPattanshetti Ofcs, I do!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

make hight match_parent for relativeLayout and ScrollView both like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="sdsd"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep scroll view height as match parent and the height of everything inside it as wrap content.